# newly installed postgres startup error

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have installed postgres & also started the server. But, when I tried to start console using psql, I'm getting error like database "****"(any database) does not exists. How to resolve this error?? I don't have acces to psql shell. And is there other way to create or change startup database without accessing psql.

Comment: if you dont access to `psql` - how did you get the error?.. You dont use psql to start up Postgres - you use `pg_ctl`.. Please update question with formatted output

Comment: `psql` uses the current user's name to log in to the server. If there is no such user and database, you need to specify that manually, e.g. `psql the_database the_user` when starting psql. Alternatively you can set environment variables to overwrite the default: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: I get error when I tried to access psql using psql command.